# Retrieving an Application from TimeMachine

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.11.6
Time Machine Software:

Need to retrieve, only, an application (Simplibudget) from "Time Machine".
This would be a backup that is about six months back, with other more recent backups of this application in front of the one I want.
Have attemped but no success.

Comment: You cannot download the application again? Or you want to put the application data back from a backup?

Comment: "Have attemped but no success." doesn't really tell us anything... Does your backup go back that far? Did you find the app but were unable to restore it? etc... You need to tell us exactly what you did & what results you saw.

Answer (score 1):

The application you can [download](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simplibudget/id440983958?mt=12) from the App Store again. Once you bought it, you can download it for free again.

The data/settings from that application you should find in the 'Application Support' folder. If you didn't clean this folder yourself there is a great change it is still there. If it is gone, follow these steps:

1. Finder > Menu 'Go' > 'Go to Folder...'
2. Type in: `~/Library/Application Support/`
3. Activate Time Machine
4. Find the 'Simplibudget' folder